# Checking a button with TestNG

Tags: selenium, button, testng

I am new to the Selenium .
I need to check the availability of a button in the system and need to mark it pass and fail with AssertEquals.

Please help me .

```
@Test
public void sellercheck () throws InterruptedException
{
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      driver.findElement(By.id("UserEvent")).click();  
      //String r=Read.getvalue().get(0);
      //select the seller
      driver.findElement(By.id("LegacyNumberCriterion")).sendKeys("123456");
      driver.findElement(By.id("SuperUse")).click();
      System.out.println("seller number entered");          
      try
      {
        if(driver.findElements(By.id("OrganizationBranchId")).size()!=0)
        {
            driver.findElement(By.id("button1")).click();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The button is not available for the seller");
        }
      }
      catch(NoSuchElementException e)
      {
        System.out.println("Element does not exist!");
      }
  }
```

Comment: Provide more info as: 1. What are your exact testing steps? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3. Where are you stuck? 4. Provide error stacktrace. 5. Provide relevant HTML DOM.

Comment: 1.I need to validate after logging with an id if a button is available the test case is passed or if it is not avilable it is failed.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Can you format your code please. I can see a lot of formatting errors & syntax error as well.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Where is your `assertEquals()` check? You need to read the docs for the library you are using and see how to do this. There are also a lot of tutorials on how this works. Read those and try something before asking a question. SO is not intended as a code writing service.

Comment: @Bitz As you have edited the code, where are you stuck now? What is the difference between your Actual Step & Expected Step?

Comment: Seems to me this is more of a Java Selenium question than a TestNG question.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose from following 2 solutions which suitable to you:

**1]** Code to check element present or not using assertion in Selenium Webdriver would be something like this:

```
assertTrue(!isElementPresent(By.id("id of button")));
```

**2]** This assertion verifies that there are no matching elements in the DOM and returns the value of Zero, so the assertion passes when the element is not present. Also it would fail if it was present.

```
Assert.assertEquals(0, driver.findElement(By.id("id of button")).size());
```

Try this solution and let me know if it works.

Comment: using selenium 2.53, isElementPresent is not coming .

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code with some simple tweaks to your own code:

```
WebDriver driver;
@Test
public void sellercheck () throws InterruptedException
{
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserEvent")).click(); 
    //String r=Read.getvalue().get(0);
    //select the seller
    driver.findElement(By.id("LegacyNumberCriterion")).sendKeys("123456");
    driver.findElement(By.id("SuperUse")).click();
    System.out.println("seller number entered");
    try
    {
        if(driver.findElements(By.id("OrganizationBranchId")).size()!=0)
        {
            driver.findElement(By.id("button1")).click();
        }
        else
        {   
            System.out.println("The button is not available for the seller");
        }
    }catch(NoSuchElementException e)
    {
           System.out.println("Element does not exist!");
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you or update me the error you see.

Comment: You didn't change anything. Please take a minute to summarize what your code does, how it differs from the OP's code, and how it answers the question.